# How to replace webpack with parcel in a CRA project?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, parceljs

I have a CRA project setup and it's working fine. However I'm considering ejecting it and replacing Webpack with Parcel.js. After ejecting, what should I do? Is the `index.js` file in the `src` folder the only file I need for Parcel?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your life will be easier if you don't eject (fewer files to delete). You also don't need webpack, Parcel will be your bundler.

If your setup is still close to what CRA gives you out of the box, here's all you have to do:

1. Uninstall react-scripts: `$ npm rm react-scripts`
2. Install parcel-bundler: `$ npm i -D parcel-bundler`
3. A key difference between CRA and Parcel is that in CRA your entry is always your `src/index.js` and `public/index.html` is more like a template. In Parcel you can have any .js file as entry, but also any .html file, which is awesome. So move all files from `public` to the `src` directory, and you can go ahead and delete `public` folder since everything now is source. Since your new entry is `index.html` lets make it point to the files correctly.
4. Remove the template variable `%PUBLIC_URL%` in your `index.html` and point to the files directly. Lets say if you placed `index.html` and `file.ext` both at the root of your `src` folder, `href="%PUBLIC_URL%/file.ext"` should become `href="./file.ext"`.
5. CRA injects a `<script />` tag to the end of your html automatically, but in Parcel you need it specified so it knows what to bundle. So add `<script src="./index.js" />` to the *bottom* of your body tag file, right before `</body>` (if you put it above your `#root` it won't work).
6. Replace your CRA `package.json` tasks with Parcel's:

Change your scripts from

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

to

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "parcel src/index.html",
  "prebuild": "rm -rf dist/",
  "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
}
```

Parcel has no `eject` and doesn't do `test`. Your `start` and `build` command will both output files to your `dist` folder, that's why it is a good idea to delete it before building. Also, add `.cache` and `/dist` to your `.gitignore`.

That's it. Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: I also had to add a .babelrc file with {"presets": ["react-app"]} and install the presets: npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react-app