# I have created a project using create-react-app with typescript, now i want to use PARCEL as my build tool. how to migrate from CRA to PARCEL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, migration, create-react-app, parcel

I have created a project using create-react-app with typescript, now i want to use PARCEL as my build tool. how to migrate my existing project from CRA to PARCEL, what do i need, please someone tell in detail

I have tried to explore the internet not many resources are available for that, not in youtube.

Comment: Its a bit challenging since these tools have different project structures and build configurations. I would recommend to create your project with parcel

Comment: it's not my personal project, it's an existing project and we have to migrate the boilerplate to PARCEL from CRA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152474/how-to-replace-webpack-with-parcel-in-a-cra-project Might help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.